# How to fetch some data from a webService to our Activity in android../

Tags: android, web-services, android-activity, webview, webviewclient

I am working on a project where i have to use an Existing web Sevice(A payment gateway provided by third party vendor) through my android APP.

My problem is after the Payment procedure is done. I want to return its data(transaction ID and Date) back to the activity so that order placement can be confirmed.`

The webService is loaded with help of webView browser using its loadUrl(Uri url) method.

(Given that I have no access to the code of Webservice how could i fetch data  back to my Activity).

Please provide me an appropriate solution.

EDIT:

Webpages corresponded to Payement gateway webservice already Exists and I am loading them through my webView.

```
Now as soon as 4 webPages are traversed and Payement procedure is done i want to send data back to the HOST Activity.
```

Comment: what type of webservice is used?. soap, json, rest??. You can use asynctask, service or other open source libraries like robospice to download data from server.

Comment: is it a SOAP/rest web service, whatever be it, it is a network call so an appropriate HTTP call is required, until nd unless u provide more data, how can we help

Comment: Is there any callback?

Comment: Really not sure you should be using this method (The webview) - typically services provide another avenue for you application to interact directly with the server via json or the like using an http connection directly (as opposed to a webview and url)

Comment: @Abhilash i dont know if dere is any callback or no since it is developed by third party.

Comment: @instead of saying it purely webServices we might say webpages already exist for the service and i just want to laod them through browser..

Comment: @Elemental if webView should not be used..shall i reroute the application direct to the browser..but how do i come back to application then..?

Comment: Check the third party developers docs/support? Sounds like there should be a callback if it's a payment service that's ment to be implemented in an app.

Comment: This is the answer to your question. Check the answer section.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583324/android-activity-to-webview-and-webview-to-activity-parameter-passing.