# Android Activity to WebView and WebView to Activity Parameter Passing

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have an application in which an activity communicates with our server and gets the outstanding amount details. I want users to pay the outstanding amount using a payment gateway. for Payment Gateway, I have to call web page from webview and transfer outstanding amount details and other credentials from activity to the page loaded in webview. At the end of transaction I once again need to get some parameters back from webpage in webview to activity.

This is a two way communication which I want to achieve between an activity and a page loaded in webview. I tried to find out a way to do it but could not find a simple example which does such exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could achieve what you want using a javascript WebAppInterface as demonstrated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript).

The main concept is that, you create a javascript interface inside the Activity holding your WebView.

```java
private class WebPayInterface {
    int amount;
    boolean success;

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void PaymentFinished(int amount, boolean success) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.success = success;

        // do whatever you want in the parent activity.
    }
}
```

Add the interface to your webView

```java
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebPayInterface(), "WebPayInterface");
```

Finally in your html code using javascript you can call

```
WebPayInterface.PaymentFinished(100, true);
```

Comment: Your comments seems to solve my second part which is webpage to activity communication. Still activity to webpage parameter passing is left.

Comment: If your webpage is in your control (you can alter server code) then you could append arguments to your url that you load in your `webview.loadUrl("http://myserver.com/mypage?param1=foo&param2=bar");`

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `Intent.putExtra()` while navigating using Intents, Shared Preferences and also Bundle. Please read Android documentation for [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29), [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)