# How to execute HTML events in Android?

Tags: android

In my app, I need a way to load HTML pages from the web, not display it, but execute DOM events such as form submit in the context of the page. Also, the page may contain JS that needs to be executed.
I found libraries to load pages and parse them but no library to execute events.
Is there any such Android library for the said purpose?

Comment: using WebView? you might check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583324/android-activity-to-webview-and-webview-to-activity-parameter-passing to run Android functions from HTML in WebView, if you want to run javascript from android, just load it like this yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:yourFunction(yourParam)");

Comment: I do not need to display any of the page's content. I parse the page and display the information in a very different way in the app. Is there any way to prevent WebView rendering?

Comment: set the width/height of the WebView to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Use Html parser. Add Jsoup library and do whatever you required based on your stuff.

See this Example. Hope this might help you.

[HTML PARSING USING JSOUP LIBRARY](http://www.radixjob.com/2013/12/android-html-parsing-tutorial-jsoup.html)

Comment: I am using JSOUP to parse the HTML. What I need is a way to execute DOM events (mostly form submits) in context of the loaded page.