# Is it possible to pass login information from webview to android activity?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, fingerprint

I have a website which is loaded in android application through a webview. Whenever the application is started, after splash screen the webview is loaded and the login page appears (in webview), this page contains two text boxes, one for username and the other one for password. After successful login the session starts and the webpages are loaded finely.
Now I want to get the login information i.e. username and password from that login page (shown in webview) into my android activity.

Reason of getting this login information:
Actually, I want to fetch these values because I need to add fingerprint authentication option as well along with username and password. I want to provide two options to user i.e. either to login with username/password or with fingerprint..

How can I achieve this situation? As I am told that it will not be possible through webview to provide both options to users as only native android applications can achieve this situation..So kindly guide me..

I have tried many solutions but in vain.

```
public class PrimeLedgeWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    String imei,url;
    boolean isConnected;
    WP10ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prime_ledge_web);

                                        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewPrime);

        progressBar = (WP10ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.wp7progressBar);
        progressBar.showProgressBar();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

                                        if (Connection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext()))
                                        {
                                            initGUI();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(PrimeLedgeWeb.this, "Make sure to connect to Internet before proceeding!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }

                                    public void initGUI() {
                                        TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE  }, 0);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            imei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
                                        }


                                        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
                                        PrimeLedgeWeb.NetworkChangeReceiver receiver = new PrimeLedgeWeb.NetworkChangeReceiver();
                                        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


                                        NetworkDetaction networkDetaction = new NetworkDetaction(this);
                                        if (networkDetaction.isNetworkConnected()) {
                                            final URLRequest urlRequest = new URLRequest(PrimeLedgeWeb.this);

                                            if (urlRequest.url==null)
                                            {
//                                                url = "http://204.93.216.33/PrimeTex/";
                                                url = "http://204.93.216.33/PrimeTex/Home/DeviceId?DevId=" + imei;

                                                if (new NetworkDetaction(PrimeLedgeWeb.this).isNetworkConnected()) {
                                                    if (urlRequest.url == null) {
                                                        webView.loadUrl(url);

                                                        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                                                        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                                        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

                                                        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                                                            @Override
                                                            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String Url) {
                                                                if (Url != url) {
                                                                    webView.loadUrl(Url);
                                                                }
                                                                return true;
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                                                                webView.setVisibility(webView.INVISIBLE);
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String Url) {

                                                                progressBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void run() {
                                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                       // progressBar.hideProgressBar();
                                                                    }
                                                                }, 1000);

                                                                webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void run() {
                                                                        view.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
                                                                    }
                                                                }, 1000);


                                                                super.onPageFinished(view, Url);
                                                                if (!new NetworkDetaction(PrimeLedgeWeb.this).isNetworkConnected()) {
                                                                    if (!Url.endsWith("loginui.aspx")) {
                                                                        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(PrimeLedgeWeb.this, "Not connected to internet",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                                                if (new NetworkDetaction(PrimeLedgeWeb.this).isNetworkConnected()) {
                                                                    webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void run() {
                                                                            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }, 1000);
                                                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
            {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
//            progressBar.showProgressBar();
//            webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//
//            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            progressBar.hideProgressBar();
//
//            view.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
            isNetworkAvailable(context);
        }

        public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            isConnected = true;
                            if (isConnected) {
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        isConnected = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    isConnected = false;
                }
            }
            return isConnected;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this blog carefully and you will get idea how to do it 
https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8

Comment: @Mehwish Mustafa, Please find this link....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583324/android-activity-to-webview-and-webview-to-activity-parameter-passing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, you can get information from javascript to activity.

**JavaScriptInterface** using this interface you can communicate between javascript & Android.

For more information & for example you can [visit](https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8) it.